# Customer Telephone number

Tags: magento-1.9

I want to display guest customer telephone number on success page.how can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can get billing or shipping telephone by following code

```
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($this->getOrderId());
$order->getShippingAddress()->getTelephone();
$order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```

as you requested to update telephone

```
$billingAddress = Mage::getModel('sales/order_address')->load($order->getBillingAddress()->getId());

$billingAddress->setTelephone("value")->save();
```

Comment: now i want to update this number

Comment: @imtiaz did you post question on that? so i can post answer their

Comment: @imtiaz added the solution here

Answer (score 0):

Please put below code in the success.phtml file:

```
$orderid = $this->escapeHtml($this->getOrderId());
$order=Mage::getModel('sales/order')->loadByIncrementId($orderid);
$customerTelephone = $order->getBillingAddress()->getTelephone();
```